# RethinkDB - update a single document and return the changes?

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

How can I update a single document and return the changes?

According to the [doc](https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/update/), you just need to add `return_changes=True`:

```
var result = await r.table('users').get(objectId).update({name: "jonas"}, return_changes=True).run(connection)
```

But I get an error instead:

> ReferenceError: True is not defined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using/confused with Pythonic syntax for JavaScript. `return_changes=True` is an assignment/evaluation, where `True` is undefined. Just replace it with `{returnChanges: true}` -- it should work.